# how to match a url non greedy

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I am hoping that someone can help me to make this match non greedy... I am using Javascript and ASP Classic

```
.match(/(<a\s+.*?><\/a>)/ig);
```

The purpose is to extract URL's from a page in this format `<a href ></a>`

I need to capture just the url

Thanks

Comment: Oh no, not yet another lost soul trying to parse HTML with Regex. Read this answer as to why this is bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: He is not trying to parse HTML, simply capture a value that has well-defined boundaries (href="...") in a string of text. Regex as a general HTML parser does not work, for for specific value cases, it's often viable.

Comment: Oh I highly doubt it is so constrained because the address that you might have in this `href` could easily break any Regex attempt.

Comment: Like for example: `<a href='javascript:alert("Yeah!"); return false;'>Alert</a>`.

Comment: jip - i have perfect formed href's that I just needed to strip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.match(/(<a\s+.*?href="(.*?)".*?>/)/ig);
```

Comment: match(/href="(.*?)"/ig, '');  <<< I have derived this from your idea... Thanks a million it now captures href="domainname.com" just what I needed!